# Weasyprint gives Fontconfig error when used with Django

Tags: python, django, weasyprint, fontconfig

I'm trying to make an application that downloads a pdf report with data from a form. The form is done by Django, the pdf is by WeasyPrint. But they don't seem to work together.

This works fine as code outside of Django:

```
from `weasyprint` import HTML
HTML(string='test').write_pdf("./report.pdf")
```

However, when part of a Django response, like this:

```
def result(request):
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    HTML(string='test').write_pdf(buffer)
    buffer.seek(0)
    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='report.pdf')
```

I get `Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file` and my Django server closes. Any ideas on how to solve this? I'm on Windows 10, python 3.7, installed the latest versions of Django and WeasyPrint (and their dependencies) via `conda`.